# Calico Cloud - Egress domain network policy issue

Tags: networking, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-networkpolicy, calico

I am trying to configure egress traffic using domains via `Calico Cloud`.

I am aware that `DNS` feature is possible with paid `Calico Enterprise` or `Calico Cloud` as mentioned [here](https://projectcalico.docs.tigera.io/security/calico-enterprise/egress-access-controls). I am using `calico cloud` trial. I am able to access Egress traffic using `destination.nets`, however when I am using `destination.domains` it block whole egress traffic.

My Env:

```
GKE cluster: 1.20.15-gke.3400
Calico version: Calico Cloud (Already connected cluster, Network Policy created via Calico Cloud UI)
Firewalls: Disabled
```

For tests I'm using default `nginx` pod with installed `ping`. I've tried to `ping` or `curl`. To make it easier, I've allowed any protocol.

**Working config with nets:**

```
apiVersion: projectcalico.org/v3
kind: GlobalNetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: default.allow-google
spec:
  tier: default
  order: 0
  selector: app == "nginx"
  namespaceSelector: ''
  serviceAccountSelector: ''
  egress:
    - action: Allow
      source: {}
      destination:
        nets:
          - 142.250.185.132/32 ## ip of www.google.com
          - 87.248.100.216/32  ## ip of www.yahoo.com
  doNotTrack: false
  applyOnForward: false
  preDNAT: false
  types:
    - Egress
```

**Issued policy using domains:**

```
apiVersion: projectcalico.org/v3
kind: GlobalNetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: default.allow-google
spec:
  tier: default
  order: 0
  selector: app == "nginx"
  namespaceSelector: ''
  serviceAccountSelector: ''
  egress:
    - action: Allow
      source: {}
      destination:
        domains:
          - '*.google.com'
          - '*.yahoo.com'
          - google.com
          - yahoo.com
  doNotTrack: false
  applyOnForward: false
  preDNAT: false
  types:
    - Egress
```

Questions:

1. Am I missing some basic configuration? It's related with tiers (I was using default and security tier but result was the same)?
2. Is there other option to allow egress policy based on DNS (open source/workarounds)?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was lacking of `kube-dns` service policy.

When you connect your `GKE` cluster to `Calico Cloud` you don't have any policy. One you create `nets` rule, it will work as it works only on `IPs`. However, when you want to use `FQDN/DNS` you need to create policy to allow connectivity to `kube-dns` service. YAML would looks like below:

```
apiVersion: projectcalico.org/v3
kind: GlobalNetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: allow-kube-dns
spec:
  selector: all()
  egress:
    - action: Allow
      destination:
        services:
          name: kube-dns
          namespace: kube-system
```

More details can be found [here](https://github.com/projectcalico/calico/blob/79b442a53adb7d7f1fd62927d9322daf87dce9de/calico/security/service-policy.md#allow-access-to-kubernetes-dns-for-the-entire-cluster).

For troubleshooting you can check if you see any output using `host` (`$ host www.google.com`) command from `dnsutils` (`$ apt install dnsutils`).

After applying above YAML, `destination.domains` policy working as expected.